Why am I not able to swipe through 3D model canvas section in mobile view?
The page I have created has 3 sections.

Heading
Canvas section for 3D model of IPhone.
Section 2.

When I switch to mobile view and try to swipe up to see section 2 of the page, my swipe gets stuck on the canvas section and then every swipe just move the view inside the canvas.
How do I swipe past the canvas section to the section 2 of the page?
StackBlitz demo

Please see [ask]. You're expected to show some code in your question.

How would you expect the browser to distinguish canvas manipulation intent from page scroll intent? That section has different UX behavior as priority. You'll need some non-canvas space alongside or overlaid to allow scroll.

Sorry, I'm new to Three JS, I have also provided the link to the demo.

It really has nothing to do with ThreeJS. It's a fundamental problem of input priority that would exist with any such situation. I see that you left a link. I clicked it. Did you click mine? In particular, see Help others reproduce the problem.
